# url normalization on apache level

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, web-server

My problem is I need to implement URL normalization according to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Url_normalization). I see few ways how to do this. The first one is to do this on the level of web application, when unnormalized url is comming in, regex checks is normalization, and in case when it's unnormalized redirect it to normalized one.

The second one, to do the same on web-server level. If there is any mod for apache or gnix which delas with it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

yes mod_rewrite does this

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html